# Efficient way of using auto complete in Linux

Tags: linux, command

Guys What is a more efficient way of doing the following using auto-complete?

```
cd
ls
cd bar
ls
cd baz
ls
cd basilio
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ls -R` from the outermost folder, that will recursively list all content.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified in which SHELL. In BASH you can do double-tab to see what are your options:

> cd [TAB] [TAB] type first few letters [TAB] to complete.

Similar - but better - completion is implemented in ZSH.